# Highlight rows in HTML table (hovered over row and preceding rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Assuming an example table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Head 1</th>
     <th>Head 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 5</td>
      <td>Data 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 7</td>
      <td>Data 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm looking for the best technique to highlight the rows <= n, where n is the hovered over row (excluding the header row). For example, if the mouse is over

```
<tr>
  <td>Data 5</td>
  <td>Data 6</td>
</tr>
```

the following part of the table should be highlighted:

```
<tr>
  <td>Data 1</td>
  <td>Data 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Data 3</td>
  <td>Data 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Data 5</td>
  <td>Data 6</td>
</tr>
```

Any ideas how this effect could be achieved?

Comment: You should really use thead and tbody!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, you could see the thing **the opposite way** : any `tr` after hovered `tr` should have no background:
test this :

```
table:hover tr {
  background:gray;
}
table:hover tr:hover ~tr {
  background:none;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/full/owIHE)

---

=============== EDITED from request in comments ================

[React only on last element in row](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/full/apsAd).

**BEWARE** :This option doesn't allow to click in cells but last one of each row.

---

```
table {
  pointer-events:none;
}
table tr :last-child {
  pointer-events:auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Nice work! add td to the two rules to stop highlighting the table headers

Comment: thanks, someone disliked it , can i have an explanation unless , it is about obsolete browsers :)

Comment: really nice solution! OP should make valid markup `<thead>`..`</thead> <tbody>`..`</tbody>` then it is perfect.

Comment: @GCyrillus It supports most browsers very well (unless you're still supporting IE6): http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector

Comment: @ElGavilan older IEs would have the problem with `:hover`, not the selector.

Comment: @GCyrillus: Thanks for the quick answer. Is it possible to change it so that only the last column activates the highlight? In other words, the whole rows should be highlighted, but only when the mouse is over the last column (in this case, the second column).

Comment: Actually, you may try to catch pointer events. @endriu answer updated with css possibilitie

Comment: @GCyrillus: Perfect! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
(fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5SLN3/)

```
$('tr').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover').prevAll().addClass('hover');
    },
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('hover').prevAll().removeClass('hover');
    }
)
```

and the style:

```
<style>
tr.hover td{background-color:#888}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there is not previous selector, you need to sort of do the opposite. Add a hove to the tbody and chnage the color of the rows after the row that was chosen.

**HTML:**

```
<table class="hovTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Head 1</th>
            <th>Head 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 3</td>
            <td>Data 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 5</td>
            <td>Data 6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 7</td>
            <td>Data 8</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hovTable, tr, td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;    
}

.hovTable tbody td {
    background-color: #FFF;    
}

.hovTable tbody:hover td {
    background-color: #CCC;    
}

.hovTable tbody:hover tr:hover ~ tr td {
    background-color: #FFF;    
}
```

**Example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rP9NY/1/)

**References:**

[General Sibling Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't choose two answers, but I marked yours as helpful. Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
var nameOfRows = "row"
//useful when there are other tables in your document.
//use like this
//<table>
//...<tr name="row">...</tr><tr name="row">...</tr>...
var backgroundOriginal = "#ffffff"; //background when the row isn't selected
var backgroundHover = "#ff0000"; //background when the row is selected;

function setHigh (id)
{
     var rows = document.getElementsByName(nameOfRows);
     for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
     {
           rows[i].style.background = backgroundOriginal;
     }
     for (i = 0; i <= id; i++) {
          rows[i].style.background = backgroundHover;
     }
}

for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName(nameOfRows).length; i++)
{
     document.getElementsByName(nameOfRows)[i].onmouseover = setHigh(i);
}
```

Try this out. I've not tested it yet, but I think it should work!

Comment: You got a bug...  `onmouseover = setHigh(i);`